# it is legal to use ' . ' and '/' in field values

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

i have read this in the docs Firstore docs ..

[image]

it says about (field namse) , but i am not sure if it also with their values too .

does it problem if i write `'/'` and `'.'` in the field values and not names

and what does 'they require extra escaping'  means exactly

```
File file = '/appFolrder/testFolder/audioFile.acc'
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").set({
"myPath":file.path  // here i write the path file which contains '/' and '.'        
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation says, this recommendation applies to field **names** and not to their *values*. That also means the code you showed does not need to escape any characters in the `file.path` value.